# Subject-Verb Agreement in "Neither" Comparison (see example)

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I am not sure about the form of the verb that follows "neither". Should it be a singular or plural verb?

For example:

> Admittedly, being a celebrity is not easy, but neither **are** being many other professionals who, unfortunately, receive much less compensation.

P.S. I came across another sentence on the Internet that says "Being single is not easy, but neither is being married."  Here, the verb following "neither" is singular. So, may I ask what is the rule here?

Comment: You are mixing two totally, completely different meanings sharing the same spelling.

Comment: If you are a speaker of other languages learning English, I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Please don't post the same question on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your example is one of logic and congruence -

> ...neither **are** being many other professionals...

doesn't work, because the subject is a singular second person state of being. However,

> ...neither **is** being many other professionals...

doesn't work either, because (unless you're a New Age spiritualist) a singular state of being cannot transform mid-sentence into a plural state of being.

The solution is to rephrase. Use something like

> ...the job of a celebrity is not easy, but neither are the jobs of many other professionals...

or

> ...being a celebrity is not easy, but neither is being another type of professional who, unfortunately, receives much less compensation.

Either of these would be much more logical and congruent than your example.